# selenium webdriver-Job Details setup

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsEXq.png)      Job Details Setup

I am not able to locate any elements on the above HTML anchor link to click on the job details setup.

Have tried linkText, xpath, class etc but unable to click on the job details setup.

Comment: what link? there is no link

Comment: <a href="http://apps.gamonoid.com/icehrm-open/?g=admin&n=jobs&m=admin_Admin" data-turbolinks="true" style="margin-left: 10px;">
<i class="fa fa-columns"></i>
Job Details Setup
</a>

Comment: thanks yahya for letting me know

Comment: is this your full HTML? just paste your full page HTML

Comment: did you facing any exceptions?